# Catch the form and the formsets errors in one statement/conditions

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a form in the form I have multiple inline formsets.

I want to catch the form and formsets errors in one statement/condition so I can let the user a message at top to check for errors:

```
'You have errors see the marked fields bellow"
```

I tried:

```
{% if form.errors  or form.non_field_errors %}
```

but it doesn't catch formsets errors.

I know I can get the formset errors:

```
formset.errors
```

and/or loop thru form in formsets for errors,

but I want the message at the top of the form, plus something that I can use generic, indifferent of the the names of the formsets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
{% if form.errors %}
    {% for field in form %}
        {% for error in field.errors %}
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```